# Prize pool distribution

Tags: multivariable-calculus, normal-distribution

I trying to create a formula that will payout 100% of a prize pool amongst 15%(rounded up or down accordingly) of the remaining field. The percentage of the payout received will scale downward with 1st place position receiving approximately 33% at 10 payouts, and will decrease in % to approx 18% at 100 payouts. The final place payout would ideally, at least, look fixed, varying from around 2x down to a minimum of 1.5x the entry fee. Each entry fee has a specific amount taken out to pay for the tournament.

Example:

The tournament entry fee is 120, with 20 taken out for staffing, and there are 70 entrants at the close of registration. There a 10 payout spots:
0.331889759273489,
0.21583823906482,
0.142287162460325,
0.0956719965413158,
0.0661282591281787,
0.0474040434544022,
0.0355370190595064,
0.0280159420519241,
0.0232492374871038,
0.0202281977629564,

Which pays out 100.6% of the prize pool. 
Anything not clear? Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the unknown?  Can you give a specific example that you're trying to solve?  Also, you state requirements in terms of the entry fee and in terms of the payoff pool, but it's not entirely clear what the relationship between these are.  Does the management always take out 20% for expenses, or is the percentage higher in smaller pools?

Comment: The amount taken out varies, with 20% taken out from 100-300, 15% from 300-500 and 10% taken out from 500+. The unknown is how to go about framing the formula. Is there someway to directly tie the number of paid places to the skew of a multivariable, or tie it to the rotation of a parabola, to have a line intesect those points that add up to 100%? The goal is to create a formula that adjusts to an increasing amount of paid positions, that distributes the total prize in an exponentially decaying format.

Comment: I think the real problem im having is accomodating distribution on an increasing number of payouts. Creating the function for distributing 100% of the prize pool to a fixed number of payouts is easy enough.

Comment: If you want each prize to be a fixed percentage of the previous prize, which is what I take "exponentially decaying format" to mean then you can't do it.   But you haven't done it in the example you posted.  You already seem to have a formula of sorts in mind for the top prize.  Decide on a fraction of that for the first few prizes, say the second through the sixth. Say you've distributed half the pot.  Decide how many will share the next 20% of the pot.  Have their winnings decrease arithmetically, instead of geometrically, so you get an equation you can solve.  Proceed like this.

Comment: Splitting up the prize pool into 2 sections was the first thing i tried. I had the pot split 1-9 and10-18+, however there was a glaring problem with the payouts between 9 and 10 when calculating higher turnouts. It was impossible to keep to scale, so i tried breaking it down again, and again, until I figured that it would be easier with an integral. I know that a fixed % wont work, and by “exponential decay” I mean exactly that: A = Pe^kt.

Comment: But in order for this formula to work, I think I have to apply that formula again to the exponent, to accomodate the payout position extending. A=Pe^(kt^(Pe^kt)) I understand the concept, however i have a hard time translating it into mathematical language, and im sorry about the terminology as Im self taught. I have a hard time visualizing such few dimensions.

Comment: The reason I havent put an example of it scaling out to higher places, is, that if I had a method to do it perfectly, I wouldn't be here asking. I will go thru the work that Ive done and try to streamline it, then find an example of it scaling.